# IOS 9 background iBeacon detection

Tags: swift, ios9, xcode7

While working with xCode 7 in swift, i can´t range beacons in background only when the app is in foreground.

My core location didRangeBeacons is that follows

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didRangeBeacons beacons: [CLBeacon], inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {

    let near = beacons[0]
    print(near)


}
```

The didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is the one that follows. Location manager object is global to the class.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.




    if(locationManager.respondsToSelector("requestAlwaysAuthorization")) {
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

    locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
    locationManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    return true
}
```

In my .plist file i have the NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription set and in the capabilities i have the background modes on with the location updates and uses bluetooth LE accessories checked.

Also i have the CoreLocation Framework added to the project.

Would very much appreciate the help or some URL´S that may help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve that. Core location adds the **allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates** witch defaults to no. You can see the video (https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=714).